# How to implement this interface so I can run function just based on their name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
export interface TransformingOptions<T, R> {
    data: T
    // function call with implementation of function parameters
    mapToBoolean?:(data: T, args:R)=> boolean
    maskBooleanToYesNo<T, argsT>(data: T,args:R)=> string
}
```

Here is the interface that I have, here are the transformer params

```
export interface TransformerParamaters {
    key: string
    value?: string | number | boolean
    args?: string | number[]

}
```

Here is

```
export const MaskingFunctions = {
    maskBooleanToYesNo<T, argsT>(data: T, args: argsT ) {
        const extractedValue = get(data, args.key)
        return extractedValue === true ? 'Yes' : extractedValue === false ? 'No' : null
    }
}
```

When i iterate through interfaces, in one of the properties i have a field that contains the name of these functions.

I want to run this dynamically

```
return TransformFunctions[mappingInterface.func]<Record<string,any>, TransformerParamaters>(data,...mappingInterface.args})
```

```
export const MaskingFunctions = {
    maskBooleanToYesNo<T, argsT>(data: T, args: argsT ) {
        const extractedValue = get(data, args.key)
        return extractedValue === true ? 'Yes' : extractedValue === false ? 'No' : null
    }
}
```

Property 'key' does not exist on type 'argsT'.

This can be compiled:

```
return TransformFunctions[mappingInterface.func]<Record<string,any>, TransformerParamaters>(data,...mappingInterface.args})
```

But i need to set the stuff before so it can run

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot. Please [edit] your question to include that. When I tried to [put one together from your code](https://tsplay.dev/N9a7MN), I get syntax errors and at least one missing function. If you put the minimal in your question that produces the errors you are getting, then maybe we can help.